# Creating object of a Class variable

Tags: java

I have a `Class` object, `clazz`. I want to make the object of that type class.

i.e. `Class clazz = MTable.getClass(tableName);`

The variable `clazz` may be of type `MOrder.class`, `MInventory.class`, or `MSalary.class`.
Now I want to make the object of `MOrder` for an instance.
Without comparing the `clazz` with `MOrder.class`, how can I create object of `MOrder`.
Is Java providing any such mechanism?

Update:

I tried this:

```
Class<? extends DocAction> clazz = (Class<? extends DocAction>) MTable.getClass(re.tableName);
        DocAction instance = null;
        try {
                instance = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But an exception is thrown:

> java.lang.InstantiationException: org.compiere.model.MOrder

Comment: What do you want to do if you get `MInventory.class` or `MSalary.class`? Why not instantiate `MOrder` directly?

Comment: I have several classes; not only MInventory, MSalary or MOrder; So instantiate all those classes are difficult. Another hope is that, all those Classes are implemented an interface DocAction.class

Comment: So you want to instantiate other classes than MOrder, but not all classes? How do you decide whether to instantiate or not? Your error is probably caused by MOrder not having a default constructor by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object object = clazz.newInstance();
```

would create the instance based on the value of `clazz`.

If you want to store the object in a `MOrder` variable, you have to check its type first :

```
MOrder order = null;
if (object instanceof MOrder) {
    order = (MOrder) order;
}
```

You can't avoid the testing of the type, since as you said, `clazz` may contain different Class instances.

If all of your classes implement DocAction interface, you can do the following :

```
Class<? extends DocAction> clazz = ...
DocAction instance = clazz.newInstace();
```

This would at least give you a reference of the type of the interface. You would still need to check the specific type if you want to store the instance in a more specific variable.

Comment: `You can't avoid the testing of the type`. Thanks. But if I have n number of class types its difficult to check each and every one. There is a hope: all those classes implements an interface called `DocAction`, then is there any chance of getting the corresponding method declared in DocAction?

Comment: Thanks for your thought. I am getting the `java.lang.InstantiationException`

Comment: I have updated the question with the code which gives me the exception.

Comment: @Sej What is the value of `clazz` for which you get this exception?

Comment: it is the right one : `class org.compiere.model.MOrder`

Comment: @Saj some reasons for this exception : the class object (clazz) represents an abstract class, an interface, an array class, a primitive type, or void, or the class has no nullary constructor

Comment: @Saj Is `org.compiere.model.MOrder` a concrete (not abstact) class? And does it have a constructor with no parameters?

Comment: its a concrete class. But it do not have the constructur with no parameters

Comment: So I need to create the parameter based instance. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64778/discussion-between-saj-and-eran).

Comment: @Saj newInstance invokes the constructor with no parameters, so it must exist. If your class has no constructors at all, the compiler will automatically generate a parameter-less constructor, but if you have a constructor with parameters, it won't.

Comment: I have the constructor as: MOrder(Properties ctx, integer PKey, Transaction trx). This is the common structure of all of the classes which implements DocAction

Comment: @Saj newInstance can't call your constructor. You must add a constructor `MOrder()` (no params)

Comment: Should I need to create a parameter less constructor? Or is there any other solution? Because I need to change the structure of all those classes.

Comment: How can we create parameter based constructure in this situation?

Comment: @Saj You have to create that constructor in order for clazz.newInstance() to work.

Comment: @Saj Using constructors with parameters would make the code more complicated - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671649/java-newinstance-of-class-that-has-no-default-constructor).

Comment: Yes. its slight complected.

Comment: I'm sure that you mean `order = (MOrder) object` instead, right?;

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Object object = clazz.newInstance()
```

Comment: So we have the type of Object. right? I want the specific object of type `MOrder`

Comment: Just cast it? `MOrder order = (MOrder) clazz.newInstance();`

Comment: @Ishkafel Then you get a ClassCastException, if the class is not a `MOrder.class`

Comment: @Ishkafel there could be 3 kind of class

Answer (score 1):

@Saj, the Class object is not inherited by your classes, so MOrder.class or MInventory.class can't be type of Class object. All object inherits from Object class, and even Class object inherits from Object class. So, your logic seems incorrect. Think in terms other way to know which type of Object to create.