# How to instantiated a class from class type at run time?

Tags: java

Consider the following attempt that doesn't quite work

```
public void createClass() {
    try {
        MyClass b = (MyClass)getMyClassType().newInstance();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

public Class<?> getMyClassType() {
    MyClass a = new MyClass(1);
    return a.getClass();
}


public class MyClass {
    private int k = 0;
    public MyClass(int t) {
        k = t;
    }

}
```

The above gets

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
```

I am not quite sure why it doesn't work.

Essentially I want to be able to create class from class type, preferably something like this

```
 Map<String, ClassType> a = new HashMap<>()

 a.get("myClassName").createClassInstanceFromClassType(constructorParam1);
```

Is the above possible in java?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094575/creating-an-instance-using-the-class-name-and-calling-constructor

Comment: `Class.newInstance()` attempts to use the no-argument constructor which `MyClass` doesn't have.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671649/java-newinstance-of-class-that-has-no-default-constructor

Answer (score 2):

The `Class.newInstance` method creates a new instance of the class using the no-argument constructor.  However, `MyClass` doesn't have a no-argument constructor; it has only the one-argument constructor you gave it.  That is why you got a `NoSuchMethodException`.  Besides, the method `Class.newInstance` has been deprecated since Java 9.

Use the [`getDeclaredConstructor` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) to pass in the parameter types expected in the constructor to find.  Then you can pass in the argument to the constructor as an argument to `newInstance`.

```
MyClass b = (MyClass) getMyClassType().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class).newInstance(1);
```

Additionally, you can change the return type of `getMyClassType` to `Class<? extends MyClass>`.  This allows you to remove the cast to `MyClass` above.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, is called a constructor.

If a class does not have a constructor declared, then the JVM will implicitly create one for you.

What you are trying to do, is quite simply achieved by using the `new` keyword.

In its very own essence, this is what you want:

```
class MyClass{

    MyClass(){
     //your implementation
    }
}



class AnotherClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    }
}
```